# Update a column in table containing XML data using LINQ-to-SQL

Tags: xml, linq-to-sql

I am using LINQ-to-SQL to create and maintain a table in SQL which contains the XML messages sent to another application and their corresponding response. Each row in the table contains the details of either a request message or a response message and the ID of the associated message (the id of the request message in the case of a response message and vice versa).

This all works well until I try to update the column containing the id of the associated response message in the request message row. To do this I am using code of the form:

```
using (var MessageStore = new MessageStore(CONNECTION_STRING))
{
     // Get the Request message with the specified ID
     var Request = MessageStore.XMLMessages.SingleOrDefault(X => X.Id == RequestId);                  

     // Update the row with the ID of the associated response message
     if (Request != null)
     {
          Request.LinkedMessageId = ResponseId;
          MessageStore.SubmitChanges();
     }
}
```

However, the SubmitChanges call throws an exception:

```
SQL Server does not handle comparison of NText, Text, Xml, or Image data types.
```

It looks like, SQL is comparing the XML data in the updated message with the original but I don't need that. Is there any way to just update some other column in the row without SQL tying to compare the XML data? I tried using anonymous types but these are read only so I can't update a value and then store it.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer about 5 minutes after posting the question! The trick is to set UpdateCheck to Never on the associated property

```
[Column(DbType = "Xml NOT NULL", CanBeNull = false, UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
public XElement MessageText { get; set; }
```